# How to modify properties resolved by Spring before their injection into beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to provide support for external preperties decryption in Spring application. I planned to use a mechanism from [spring-cloud-config](https://github.com/4finance/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/BootstrapApplicationListener.java), which is triggered after the `Environment` is ready and add decrypted properties with higher precedence. Unfortunately it heavily relies on Spring Boot bootstrap mechanism which emits `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent`. Looking into the Spring Framework code the environment and context creation is highly coupled and it would be rather hard to run my own code between that. The application I am working with is a large, multi module "standard" Spring MVC application and I would not like to convert it into Spring boot application right now.

**Question**:

How could I execute my code after the environment was created and before the context creation (to modify properties before they will be injected into "normal" beans) in Spring (**not Spring Boot**) application?

**Alternative question**:

Is there any other way to get control over properties being injected into beans (for modify values originally resolved by Spring)?

Comment: Write an `ApplicationContextIntializer` which does what you want.

Comment: I have just found your comment. Please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer` which adds decryption or whatever to the `PropertySource`s of your choice.

We do something similair in one of the application I currently develop. After loading some custom properties from files and databases we wrap all the available `PropertySource`s in a `EncryptablePropertySource` because several properties are encrypted (We use the Jasypt library for that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and thanks also for pointing Jasypt. It seems to be much easier to implement in pure Spring than porting spring-cloud-config mechanism from Spring Boot. Btw, Jasypt seems a little bit abandoned. Have you had an opportunity to use it with Spring 4?

Comment: No we are still on Spring 3.2 but there is nothing that would prevent you from using it with Spring4.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Value("${propname}")` annotation on a setter method, instead of using on the field.

You can write code to handle transform/validate the property in the setter method, and then assign to the field.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but I would like to have a decryption process transparent for people using placeholders - there are many teams maintaining separated modules. In addition is it a duplication (to call decryption in every bean) and abstraction leakage - all beans have to know about decryption mechanism (to call it).

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I have found `customizeContext` method in `ContextLoader` which reads defined `ApplicationContextInitializer`s. It is executed after the environment was created and before the context is reloaded, so decryption in an initializer should work (at least in the base case):

```
ConfigurableEnvironment env = wac.getEnvironment();
(...) 
customizeContext(sc, wac);
wac.refresh();
```